# Django CMS which is the best?

Tags: django, content-management-system

I read Djangos cms comparison page and it seems

http://www.django-cms.org/

may be what I was looking for.

Any experience with that? Recommendation?

Especially on how to install it. I cant find any installation info for it.

Apart from:

"Make sure that cms, mptt and publisher folders are on your pythonpath. They all should come with the distribution."

Or what is the best and easiest to install cms for django with the least dependencies?

Comment: I haven't used it, but in general django apps should install just by being placed in your project folder, and being added to the list of installed apps.

Comment: -1 totally against the faq.

Answer (score 4):

I used Mezzanine. In general it works but I switched to Django-CMS now and am happier with it.

Here is a really straightforward way to get started: https://www.django-cms.org/en/documentation/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and selected django-cms. FeinCMS looked attractive as well.

There is a pretty good tutorial for django-cms at: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/2.1.3/. The only drawback is that there is not about the deployment on the production environment. However, you should get it done by reading django documentation at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/.