# Django: Is there a django blog or cms engine that have all wordpress features?

Tags: django, content-management-system, django-cms

as it says, I want django cms engine that have the capabilities of wordpress.

I wanna build something like [tutsplus.com](http://tutsplus.com) network but want it in python/django base.

Comment: Mezzanine resembles tools like Wordpress. I don't think it has *all* the WP features, though it might worth to have a look at it: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 3):

Django is a framework, so it would be a bit more involved than wordpress for the most part to make something like tutsplus out of the box.

Check out 
http://pinaxproject.com/ (I dig pinax) or
https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps

But you might also want to dig deeper into django based CMSs (via other posts) like:

[Django CMS which is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515320/django-cms-which-is-the-best)
[Integrate existing blog code into Django-CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099822/integrate-existing-blog-code-into-django-cms)

more detailed list of Django based CMSs here:
http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/cms/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with django-cms and I found it very well documented and easy to start with. I still have to figure out good way of putting forms into it.